# Using VALUE to make temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the purpose of dummy function abc123() in the following queries? Both of them work, but I don't understand the need for the dummy function.

I've tried to remove it, but always with syntax errors.

```
  SELECT MAX(NumbersTable) AS NumbersTable
   FROM ( VALUES (1), (3), (2) ) AS abc123(NumbersTable)

   SELECT TOP 1 NumbersTable
   FROM ( VALUES (1), (3), (2) ) AS abc123(NumbersTable)
   ORDER BY NumbersTable DESC
```

I expect the result to be 3, and that is what I get.

Comment: That is a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2):

It is not a function.  It defines the derived table created by `values`.  The `abc123` is the table alias.  The `NumbersTable` is the name of the column.

If you run:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1), (3), (2) ) AS abc123(NumbersTable)
```

You will see:

```
NumbersTable
1
2
3
```

Because `NumbersTable` is the name of the column.  You can also write:

```
SELECT abc123.NumbersTable
FROM ( VALUES (1), (3), (2) ) AS abc123(NumbersTable)
```

Comment: Yes, it's no a function, but it's a **[`Table Value Constructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!